# Trying to find the XPATH

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, soap

I am trying to find the xpath of the 'lucidId' in this SOAP return:

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://media.com/entities/lpedition" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
       <ns1:detailFromPublicationDateResponse>
          <return SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:Edition[2]" xsi:type="ns1:EditionArray">
             <item id="5267" status="" adsBundleStatus="" adsBundleSizeInBytes="" adsBundleUrl="" xsi:type="ns1:Edition" xmlns="http://lapresse.ca/entities/lpedition">
                <name>ARTS CINÉMA</name>
                <publishedAt>20170603</publishedAt>
                <sections>
                   <section id="22556" type="CAT" rank="1">
                      <typeCode>REG</typeCode>
                      <color>008591</color>
                      <name>ARTS CINÉMA</name>
                      <pages>
                         <page id="66972270" lucidId="3d84e764-c507-4f07-82c3-c6f9cab588eb|_0" pageNumberForEdition="" pageNumberForSection="1" type="" adsBundleStatus="" adsBundleSizeInBytes="0" adsBundleUrl="">
                            <navThumbnail url="http://lp-bo.lapresse.ca/api/5267/d8eb9c12f7b449dd80bf852832638ed7/thumbnail-nav">
                               <title>À la une</title>
                               <subTitle>ARTS</subTitle>
                            </navThumbnail>
                            <screenCapture url="http://lp-bo.lapresse.ca/api/5267/d8eb9c12f7b449dd80bf852832638ed7/thumbnail?lucidRank=0"/>
                            <ads/>
                            <pages/>
                            <articles/>
                            <slideshows/>
                         </page>
```

As soon as I put 'return' in my xpath, I am not getting anything

```
 /SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns1:detailFromPublicationDateResponse/return
```

I have tried with various xpath tester, and I am not getting anything...
Would it have to do anything with the array?

It does work for the xpath when I am doing: `//pages/page/@lucidId`
But in my XSL file I am not able to bypass the `return`.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
 <xsl:template match="/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns1:detailFromPublicationDateResponse/return">
  <xsl:for-each select="item/sections/section/pages/page">
     <xsl:value-of select="@lucidId"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
```

Comment: Did you try `//pages/page/@lucidId` ?

Comment: I did but when I am trying to use it in my XSL, it s not returning anything...

Comment: Everything from `item` down is in the default namespace `http://lapresse.ca/entities/lpedition`. Try binding that namespace to a prefix in your XSLT and use it in your xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Everything from `item` down is in the default namespace `http://lapresse.ca/entities/lpedition`.

Try binding that namespace to a prefix in your XSLT and use it in your xpath.

In the example below, I bind the namespace to the prefix `lp`.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:ns1="http://media.com/entities/lpedition"
  xmlns:lp="http://lapresse.ca/entities/lpedition"
  exclude-result-prefixes="SOAP-ENV ns1 lp">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns1:detailFromPublicationDateResponse/return">
    <xsl:for-each select="lp:item/lp:sections/lp:section/lp:pages/lp:page">
      <xsl:value-of select="@lucidId"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
3d84e764-c507-4f07-82c3-c6f9cab588eb|_0;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='detailFromPublicationDateResponse']/*[local-name()='return']/*[local-name()='item']/*[local-name()='sections']/*[local-name()='section']/*[local-name()='pages']/*[local-name()='page']/@lucidId
```

or just

```
//*[local-name()='pages']/*[local-name()='page']/@lucidId
```

Comment: This is not a good suggestion. Namespaces are to be used, not ignored.